# Marketing Cloud: How to not send mobile push messages to inactive devices?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Does anyone know how to prevent Salesforce from sending mobile push messages to inactive devices?

The [**documentation**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/mobilepush/contacts/who_receives_your_message/) says that no matter which filter we use, the system will always send the message to all devices associated with a contact, even if some device don't satisfy the filter.

A client of mine has a lot of contacts that have more than one device (mostly inactive).  They are wasting large numbers of messages if they send messages that will never reach a device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate exclusion list of inactive devices.  The Marketing Cloud won't send to any devices on the exclusion list.

Comment: Hi there ! Sorry for writting here few years later but this answers could help me. I'm not able to create this list of inactive devices, can you help me ? I took "status equals inactive" in MobilePush Data > MobilePush Demographics but it says I don't have any contact matching the criteria. Any idea ? Thanks in advance !